# How to set prometheus endpoint in non spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, prometheus

I want to add a path "localhost:8080/metrics" to my app to see `Counter` on my variables by using Prometheus. I read that for a spring boot application I need the only annotation over the main class.

```
package hello;

import io.prometheus.client.spring.boot.EnablePrometheusEndpoint;
import io.prometheus.client.spring.boot.EnableSpringBootMetricsCollector;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnablePrometheusEndpoint
@EnableSpringBootMetricsCollector
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

How can I obtain the same result in a non-Spring Boot application where I don't have a `@SpringBootApplication`.

Can it be achieved by registering multiple servlets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to add the Prometheus servlet to your application.

I will give an example of a Jetty server cited in [the documentation](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java#exporting):

```
Server server = new Server(1234);
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
context.setContextPath("/");
server.setHandler(context);

context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new MetricsServlet()), "/metrics");
```

The dependency [`io.prometheus.simpleclient_spring_boot`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.prometheus/simpleclient_spring_boot) is a Spring Boot integration. Instead, you should look at the core library [`io.prometheus.simpleclient`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.prometheus/simpleclient).

Comment: "io.prometheus.simpleclient" Thanks for help. Now everything is working clear.